# Serve out swagger-ui from nodejs/express project

Tags: node.js, express, swagger, swagger-ui

I would like to use the swagger-ui dist 'as-is'...well almost as-is.

Pulled down the latest release from github (2.0.24) and stuck it in a folder in my app.  I then server it out statically with express:

```
app.use('/swagger', express.static('./node_modules/swagger-ui/dist'));
```

That works as expected when I go to:

```
https://mydomain.com/swagger
```

However I want to populate the url field to my swagger json dynamically.  IE I may deploy to different domains:

```
https://mydomain.com/api-docs
https://otherdomain.com/api-docs
```

And when I visit:

```
https://mydomain.com/swagger
https://otherdomain.com/swagger
```

I would like to dynamically set the url.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the /api-docs (or swagger.json) are always on the same path, and only the domain changes, you can set the `url` parameter of the SwaggerUi object to `"/path/to/api-docs"` or `"/path/to/swagger.json"`instead of a full URL. That would make the UI load that path as relative to the domain the UI is hosted on.

For reference, I'm leaving the original answer as well, as it may prove useful in some cases.

You can use the `url` parameter to set the URL the UI should load.

That is, if you're hosting it under `https://mydomain.com/swagger` you can use `https://mydomain.com/swagger?url=https://mydomain.com/api-docs` and `https://mydomain.com/swagger?https://otherdomain.com/api-docs` to point at the different locations.

However, as far as I know, this functionality is only available at the current alpha version (which should be stable enough) and not with 2.0.24 that you use (though it's worth testing).

Comment: Yup just moved to 2.1.alpha as I am using the swagger editor which generates 2.0 docs.  Thanks!

Comment: So I can point at different locations, but still not sure how to make this dynamic within my node/express app.  Especially since I am serving out the swagger-ui statically: app.use('/swagger', express.static('./node_modules/swagger-ui/dist'));

Comment: Thanks @webron.  However still not sure there is a way to serve out static files in express with a parameter.  Again, looking more to how do I modify app.use('/swagger', express.static('./node_modules/swagger-ui/dist')); to include the url parameter.  Seems like more of a redirect, and not sure I can do that with express.static

Comment: It's not a parameter to the URL, you need to modify the index.html, specifically, https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/dist/index.html#L34. Since it's part of your application, there should be no problem modifying it (which you probably already have).

Comment: Makes sense.  However just because its part of my app doesn't mean I want to modify it, angularjs is part of my app and I don't want to modify it.  For obvious reasons.  If I can serve out swagger-ui as https://mydomain.com/swagger, no reason I shouldn't be able to server out as https://mydomain.com/swagger?url=/api-docs.

Comment: Actually, swagger-ui is *meant* to be modified, specifically the index.html, but many update the CSS files as well. Angular is a framework, Swagger-UI is a presentation tool. You're not expected to change the underlying library it uses (swagger-js) but you are expected to modify its usage based on your needs. https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui#customize and https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui#swaggerui

Comment: I have to agree with @webron on this one.  swagger-ui is a library just like AngularJS, it just happens to ship with a working default implementation.  If you look at [this implementation](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/dist/index.html#L33) you'll see that behind the scenes, this implementation just calls the `SwaggerUi` constructor with the `url` argument @webron speaks of.  In fact, I am doing exactly what @webron is suggesting in [swagger-tools' swagger-ui middleware](https://github.com/apigee-127/swagger-tools/blob/master/middleware/swagger-ui/index.html#L85).

Comment: _Continued from above..._  In the case of swagger-tools' swagger-ui middleware, I want to set the URL based on a header I retrieve so that the server can dictate the value.  This is very similar to what you're wanting to do.

Comment: Possible work to break apart config from UI, https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/804#issuecomment-68647819 This should help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Another method would be to use the swagger-ui middleware located in the swagger-tool.

```
let swaggerUi = require('../node_modules/swagger-tools/middleware/swagger-ui');
app.use(swaggerUi(config.swagger));
```

The variable `config.swagger` contains the `swagger.yaml` or `swagger.json`. I have in my setting

```
  let config = {
      appRoot: __dirname,
      swagger: require('./api/swagger/swagger.js')
  };
```

Note: I am using the `require('swagger-express-mw')` module

Answer (score 0):

You could try with this on index.html file of the swagger-ui... It works for me.

```
if (url && url.length > 1) {
   url = decodeURIComponent(url[1]);
} else {
   url = window.location.origin + "/path/to/swagger.json";
}
```